# Spring Data Join Query using Specification in unrelated tables

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api, specification-pattern

Have 2 entities

```
@Table(name = "REQUEST")
public class RequestEntity {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "REQUEST_ID")
   private String requestId;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "REQUEST_ID")
   private Set<StatusLogEntity> statusLogs;
   ... setters/getters
}
```

and

```
@Table(name = "STATUS_LOG")
public class StatusLogEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long statusLogId;

    @Column(name = "REQUEST_ID")
    private String requestId;
    
    ...setters/getters
}
```

Need to provide the JOIN that populates the StatusEntity Objects set.

The following Specification only returns `RequestEntity` , when asking for the `requestEntity.getStatusLogs()` the expected error

> could not initialize proxy - no Session

due to the (FetchType.LAZY) and that the StatusLogs are not being hydrated from the query.

The Specification I have is:

```
public static Specification<RequestEntity> withLogs(
        final String requestId) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {

        Root<StatusLogEntity> statusLogRoot = query.from(StatusLogEntity.class);
        root.join("statusLogs").on(builder.equal(statusLogRoot.get("requestId"), requestId));
        return builder.equal(root.get("requestId"), accountActionRequestId);
    };
}
```

Which generates the following query

```
request0_.request_id as request_1_0_,
from
    request request0_ cross 
join
    status_log statusloge1_ 
inner join
    status_log statuslogs2_ 
        on request0_.request_id=statuslogs2_.request_id 
        and (
            statusloge1_.request_id=?
        ) 
where
    request0_.request_id=?
```

How can I create a Specification that returns the Request with their respective StatusLogs?

Thanks!